# Ionic - view console.log in iOS emulator

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ios-simulator

I am working on an ionic app for iPad. In order to test the app on Mac, I am using the emulate command

```
ionic emulate ios
```

This launches the application in iOS Simulator. However, I am not able to find the console.log that I have printed in the Ionic application. After launching, it prints the following logpath in the terminal. However, the console.log file does not exist in this path

```
logPath: /Users/kayasa/myIonicApp/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
```

Upon some research I found that in order to view the console.log message, emulate command needs to be executed with -lc command. However, this command does not even start the application in Simulator correctly. The application launches with the white blank screen.

Then I also tried launching the app from within xcode itself. It does launch the app in Simulator but I can't find a way to see the console.log here as well.